# Issue running Classic ASP written in VBScript on Windows 2012 with IIS 8

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

This is a very peculiar issue. I have a 2012 Server running IIS 8  with support for classic ASP installed. I am building a comma separated string from a form. I then am retrieving this string from a table and want to split on the commas.

First, when I build the string and submit it to the DB (SQL Express 2014), something is adding a space after each comma even though there is no space in the code.

Second, when I return the string and attempt to split on the comma, it doesn't do anything; the ubound method returns -1... For testing purposes, I hand built an array and this has the same behavior.

Code that builds the csv string:

```
If fieldName = "txt_EnvironmentType" then
    strTempEnvCSV = strTempEnvCSV & fieldValue & ","
End If
```

Test code for split:

```
txtEnvironmentType = "This,Is,A,Test,String"
If txtEnvironmentType <> "" then
response.write(txtEnvironmentType)
array = split(txtEnvironmentType,",")
l = ubound(array)
response.write("<br>array is " & l & " long")
For i = LBound(array) to UBound(array)
    response.write("<br>" & array(i))
Next
End If
```

The Above test code returns the following to the browser:

```
This,Is,A,Test,String
array is -1 long
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, just for completion sake, this is what is inserted to/returned from the DB from the code that builds the csv:
Development, InfraTesting, PhasedDeployment, Production,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the mysterious spaces, add a TRIM() to make sure you aren't starting with spaces:

```
If fieldName = "txt_EnvironmentType" then
    strTempEnvCSV = strTempEnvCSV & TRIM(fieldValue) & ","
End If
```

This ran (for your second issue) for me - the only change I made was to dim the array variable and name it something other than "array"

```
<%
dim arrMine
txtEnvironmentType = "This,Is,A,Test,String"
If txtEnvironmentType <> "" then
response.write(txtEnvironmentType)
arrMine = split(txtEnvironmentType,",")
l = ubound(arrMine)
response.write("<br>arrMine is " & l & " long")
For i = LBound(arrMine) to UBound(arrMine)
    response.write("<br>" & arrMine(i))
Next
End If
%>
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  If this solved your issue, could you please accept the answer?